# Force.com Site and custom user authorization - Is it allowed and when?

Tags: community, force.com-sites, security-review, user-management, heroku

Assume I am going to build a customer facing website where users have some access to Salesforce Standard and custom objects.

Because it's expensive I don't want to give them Salesforce licenses. I also don't want to go with a Full-blown Community. The technical complexities and the costs of Heroku Connect also shy me away from Heroku.

Can I do this?

- Force.com Site
- Custom User and Permission Objects
- Custom Registration + Login using VF
- "Authentication" with Custom User object
- Only a Single Guest licence
- Giving 50 outside users access to Accounts and Lead using single Salesforce license

So my question is **not about technical feasibility**. I know that this would be possible. **It's about legal stuff**. Salesforce is in the License business and circumventing this is probably disallowed.

I need to know if and when I can do this. Can you point me to any documentation, legal material that is prohibiting that?  Maybe it is only prohibited for **ISVs** and **AppExchange packages**. Maybe it is prevented by **Security review**. Are **Consulting Partners** and **PDOs** allowed to (help) build such apps? And if not, where is that documented.

I really need some official reference material here.